# Changing the values in a database table using Entity Framework and c#

Tags: frameworks, entity

I'd like to manipulate(access and change) the values in a column that was created automatically by the code i wrote, which was making a List of "Workers" in a table was created by the code.

I have a table called "WorkConstraints" which i did not write myself, rather visual studio created it by itself.

I want to be able to manipulate the values of the columns which are located in the table.
For example, i have 2 columns: HourConstraints, WeeklyConstraints.
I want each of my "Worker" classes to be able to have values which are specific to these two columns.

For example:
I'd like John to have a name, age, HourConstraints and WeeklyConstraints.

Comment: Q:What exactly do you want to do?  An "end run" around EF, and do SQL instead?  Could you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm working with a SQL server for my tables but using EF to write the c# in visual studio.